# convert pair of arrays to array of pairs (using LINQ if possible)

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, ienumerable, valuetuple

I have some types `S` and `T` (e.g. `S=object` and `T=string`).
I have a pair of arrays of these types, i.e.

```
(S[], T[]) pairOfArrays;
```

and I want to convert it to an array of pairs, i.e.

```
(S, T)[] arrayOfPairs;
```

How do I do that? I am most interested in solutions with LINQ, if possible.
Please assume that the two arrays in `pairOfArrays` have the same length.

---

I know the other direction:

```
pairOfArrays = (arrayOfPairs.Select(i => i.Item1).ToArray(),
                arrayOfPairs.Select(i => i.Item2).ToArray());
```

The problem I have with the sought direction is: in order to iterate (use `Select` and such) I need an `IEnumerable`, but `(S[], T[])` is no `IEnumerable`. And if I start with `pairOfArrays.Item1.Select(...`, then I don't know how to get to the same entry (index-wise) of `Item2` as I currently have inside my `Select` statement.

Comment: You can use `Zip` for this.

Comment: I usually use something like this : var arrayOfPairs = S.Select((x,i) => new object[] { s = x, t = T[i] }).ToArray();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip) for this:

```
var result = arrayOfS.Zip(arrayOfT, (first, second) => new { S = first, T = second });
```

which results in a list of `{ S, T }`.

Alternativly a good old-style loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfS.Length; i++)
{
    result[i] = new ST(arrayOfS[i], arrayOfT[i]);
}
```

However this way you can´t use anonymous types.

Comment: Or like this: `arrayOfPairs = pairOfArrays.Item1.Zip(pairOfArrays.Item2, (s, t) => (s, t)).ToArray();`

Comment: @Kjara If you need an array, then yes.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Also the OP seems to want value tuples, not an anonymous class.

Comment: @juharr True, but I omitted it, as Aomine already considered this.

Answer (score 5):

Using `Zip`, you can get the corresponding elements and transform them into Tuples:

```
var arrayOfPairs = pairOfArrays.Item1.Zip(pairOfArrays.Item2, (f, s) => new Tuple<S, string>(f, s))
                               .ToArray();
```

or as of C#7:

```
var arrayOfPairs = pairOfArrays.Item1.Zip(pairOfArrays.Item2, (f, s) => (f, s))
                               .ToArray();
```

a less idiomatic approach than the above but still a good solution would be using `Enumerable.Range`:

```
var arrayOfPairs = 
    Enumerable.Range(0, pairOfArrays.Item1.Length)
            .Select(index => (pairOfArrays.Item1[index], pairOfArrays.Item2[index]))
            .ToArray();
```

Comment: Nice use for C#7-tuple.